# Accessing DOM with JS

Tags: javascript

I am taking up JS on my own. This endeavor exposes me to various ways of achieving the same thing in JS. Particularly, I wondering about the correctness of the following ways of working with the DOM.

I have a simple html page

```
<body>
        <h1 class="red">I am red</h1>
        <h2 class="blue">I am blue</h2>
        <h3 class="yellow">I am yellow</h3>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here, I am trying to change the color of the html elements with a click event

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (!(event.target === document.body)) {
        event.target.style.color = event.target.classList;
    }
});



Array.from(document.body.children).forEach((child) => {
    child.addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.style.color = this.classList;
    });
});
```

Comment: you have added  !   in your if condition so this why not working.

Comment: The code works as intended. I placed ! in the condition to prevent the event-handler from firing when the body element is clicked. I only want the event-handler to be invoked when the child elements of the body is clicked on

Comment: @kbl is your intention to _permanently_ change the element's styles on click or just when during the keypress?

Comment: @StuckDuck I wanted the color of the elements to change when the elements are clicked on

Comment: @kbl that didn't answer my question